# How to scale area light icon in viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, light, scale

I placed an area light in my scene. Its icon appeared to be unreasonably long. Is there a way to shorten it in the viewport?

[image: Area light being super long]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scale rectangle with <kbd>S</kbd> or when you bring cursor closer to rectangle, drag the corner handle.

---

But I would say you are asking how to change light **Distance** represented by a line. For that you would have to go to *Light Properties > Custom Distance* and change parametr (even when it is disabled it change the widget).

It is accessible only via Eevee. Seems like it would need a touch of GUI designer :)

[image]